# How to retrieve data into a <textarea> HTML tag in C# / Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, textarea, datalist

Using DataList, it's not possible to collect data into a `<textarea></textarea>` HTML tag. Because Visual Studio automaticly adds `table` and so `td` and shows data in these HTML tags.

I want to show bunch of "added tags" in a passive-looking `<textarea>`. How can I do it? Is it possible to use data piece by piece WITHOUT any pre-constructed HTML tag. I don't want any `td`...

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a repeater :

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="rpGeneratedTags">
  <headertemplate>
    <textarea name="generatedTags">
  </headertemplate>
  <footertemplate>
    </textarea>
  </footertemplate>
  <itemtemplate>
    <%# System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode((string)Eval("Tag") %#>
  </itemtemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```